# TypeError: grid.mongo.ObjectID is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I've got this JS code for my Next.js API. I'm trying to store images in MongoDB GridFS and retrieve them with a simple API route. The code you are seeing is from a file that gets imported in the API route.

```js
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"
import Grid from "gridfs-stream"

const { MONGODB_URI, MONGODB_DB } = process.env

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local"
  )
}

if (!MONGODB_DB) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGODB_DB environment variable inside .env.local"
  )
}

let cached = global.mongo

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

export async function connectToDatabase(dbIndex = 0) {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((client) => {
      const db = client.db(MONGODB_DB.split(",")[dbIndex])
      const grid = Grid(db, MongoClient)
      grid.collection("fs.files")
      return {
        client,
        db: db,
        gfs: grid
      }
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}
```

When I try to use `createReadStream` I get the following error:

`TypeError: grid.mongo.ObjectID is not a constructor`

The issue is with `const grid = Grid(db, MongoClient)`  but I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Fixed the issue. I wasn't meant to use `grid.collection`.

Comment: How/where are you calling `createReadStream`?

Comment: ```import { connectToDatabase } from "../../../util/mongodb"

export default async ({ query: { filename } }, res) => {
  const { gfs } = await connectToDatabase(1)
  const readStream = gfs.createReadStream({
    filename: filename
  });

  readStream.on('error', (err) => {
    res.status(404).json({
      error: `Couldn't find that image.`
    })
  });

  readStream.pipe(res)
  res.status(200)
}
```

Comment: that's my API route

Comment: Please move additional, relevant code to the question.

Comment: dw I fixed the issue. it was `grid.collection()`.

Comment: Heyy @QuaKe what was the issue with grid.collection? could you please tell a little more

Comment: Can you please write down your solution as an answer below. It can be useful for us.